# Confusion regarding conditional probability

Tags: probability

Let's take an example. I am throwing a fair dice many times. I want to get a $6$. Every time I throw the dice , probability of getting $6$ is $\frac{1}{6}$. Suppose that I haven't got a $6$ for $20$ consecutive times, then what is the probability of getting $6$ on $21^{st}$ roll? Is it $1/6$ or $(5/6)^{20}*1/6$ or anything else?

I am confused because the dice doesn't know it did not get $6$ for so many times

Comment: The probabilities are independent, so it will still be 1/6

Comment: @MathLover I mean probabilty of any specific number is 1/6

Comment: Use $P(A\mid B)=P(A\cap B)/P(B)$ with $A=[$get $6$ on roll $21]$ and $B=[$no $6$ during rolls $1$ to $20]$, then $P(A\cap B)=(1/6)(5/6)^{20}$ and $P(B)=(5/6)^{20}$ hence $P(A\mid B)=$ $____$.

Comment: what probability do you want ? the probability of getting 6 after 21 tosses ? because otherwise the probability is still 1/6 since the die is fair

Comment: @Idle001 yes I want probability of 6 on 21st roll

Comment: The confusion is an extremely common one to beginning students of probability, and it boils down to distinguishing conditional probabilities from probabilities of intersections. You're asking for a conditional probability in your question, which because the die rolls are independent, is just $1/6.$ If you ask instead "what is the probability of seeing $20$ consecutive non-$6$s, followed by a $6$?" the answer is the probability of an intersection, and is $(5/6)^{20}(1/6)$ (computed using independence of the rolls).

Comment: @Did formula makes sense but how is it that regardless of how unlucky I have been, my chances of success are still same on next try?(am I getting philosophical?)

Comment: Dice don't have memory.  They don't know that they came up with 20 consecutive non-sixes.  And so, you can just ignore that bit of history.  Unless you want to get "meta" with the problem, and say that there is a non-zero probability that your assumptions are false, and you are in fact rolling a loaded die.

Comment: @johndoe This seems odd, because we know that on average, we should see roughly the same number of $1$s, $2$s, and so on. But for each individual roll, the probability stays the same. Thus, it would be a little weird to see a sequence of $20$ non-$6$s followed by a $6,$ but regardless of whether or not we've rolled a sequence of $20$ non-$6$s beforehand, whenever we roll a fair die, it's equally likely to hit any number.

Comment: The point where our intuition is squarely failing us is that, faced with $$666666666666666666666$$ we immediately declare it unlikely, while, when faced with $$164214462352316422356$$ we do not. But these two results are exactly as (un)likely since they both have probability $$\left(\frac16\right)^{20}\approx3\cdot10^{-16}$$ Amazing, eh?

Comment: As I 'm convinced of that the die is fair, and a die by custom doesn't take decisions, while the thrower does, his next step is based on the previous so if he hit a 6 already he wouldnt retry, because the chain of attempts would be taken from the beginning and probability is recalculated, which means P(6 at 2nd toss / 6 at first toss) is always 0 when the face 6 appears in the first throw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the die is fair, then the probability is still just $\frac{1}{6}$. Your formula $(\frac{5}{6})^{20}\cdot \frac{1}{6}$ is the probability of not getting a $6$ for $20$ consecutive throws *and* then getting a $6$ right after that.  So that would be the formula for $P(A \cap B)$, where $A$ is the event of not getting a $6$ for $20$ consecutive throws and $B$ the event for getting a $6$ on the $21$-st throw.  However, you are looking for the conditional probability $P(B|A)$, which given the independence of future throws and past throws (that is, given that the die has indeed no memory) is simply the same as $P(B)$, i.e $P(B|A) = P(B) = \frac{1}{6}$.

If this was a real life situation, however, then after not getting a $6$ for $20$ consecutive throws, I would form a slight suspicion that this may not be a fair die, and would suspect that the probability of getting a $6$ on the next throw is actually somewhat lower than $\frac{1}{6}$ ...

Answer (score 0):

No dice roll affects any future roll or previous roll - the die has no memory of its previous rolls when it rolls for you. That means, that if you do 20 rolls and they all flip up 6 (or all not 6, or 1 not 6 and 19 6s, etc.), then on your next roll there will always be a 1/6 chance of getting any of the 6 possible values.

Answer (score -1):

Let's dnote $\delta(n)$ the probability of getting 6 after $n$ shots.

$\delta(0)=1/6$ obviously

$\delta(1)=5/6*1/6=5/36$  consequently?? no! false! I will explain.

$\delta(1)$ is the chance to hit $6$ regarded failing all the other cases, because the sequence {$62$} is not taken as an option, the tosser should halt at a specific stage, when he makes his first trial. which means $\delta(1)=P(6\ after\ all\ failings)=\frac{combinations(succeeding\ a\ 2nd\ toss)}{combinations(All\ \ available\ tosses)}=\frac{5}{1+6*5}=5/31$

Extrapolating along the basis leads to ....

$\delta(20)=\frac{5^{20}}{1+5+5^2+...+5^{20}6}=\frac{5^{20}}{(5^{20}-1)/4+5^{20}6}$